# Project within a Project for Visual Studio Online?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, projects-and-solutions

I was presented with a task to create a project within a project in Visual Studio Online, but I can't seem to find anything that will be able to facilitate this, am I just not seeing it?

Comment: Do you mean you will host your VS Project using Azure?

Comment: Yes, I'm still very new to Azure Dev and VS

Comment: As of now, you can focus on development first of your website. Once done, you can use this link to deploy it in Azure: https://dzone.com/articles/how-create-and-deploy-website

Answer (score 0):

On the top right corner of the main dashboard ([https://dev.azure.com/*SomeName*](https://dev.azure.com/_SomeName_)), there's a 'Create project' button.

[image: Azure DevOps dashboard]

If you're not seeing it, you don't have the right permissions. More info at [Create a project in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/create-project?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav).

> If you're not a member of the Project Collection Administrators Group, get added as one. To create projects you must have the **Create new projects** permission set to **Allow**.

Comment: I have that available, but the request that I have received is for created a project from with a project..I'm just not sure if it's even possible, I've looked around on TN and can't seem to find anything there either.